# Is my SQL table structure correct?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named Answer where I stored the answer for different types of question that are like Google Forms Question (ShortAnswer, Paragraph, etc). The Answer table has the following structure:

```
id - integer - Primary Key
question_id - integer - Foreign Key
value - text
```

For simple types of question this table is sufficient because they only store the answer value for a specific question. However I've a Grid type of question, where I have to store an answer (or multiple answers) for a specific row of the grid, so I have to use a pivot table to store the relationship Answer-Row that keep a pair 'row_id - answer_id'. So my question is: is it correct to have this relationship in the same table that I've the other types of questions? Or should I use a different Answer table per question type?

Comment: It's generally better to describe your table in a schema that's actually SQL and can be used on tools like [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) to test things.

Comment: Are you prepared to use something like a JSON column (MySQL 5.7+) or just store JSON data in that `TEXT` field? That's a good way to accommodate unknown situations in the future, but the downside its it's not relational data, which can be a problem.

Comment: `value` is a terribly ambiguous name for a column. What is it a *value* of?

Comment: I'm going to store data form input (text, textarea, select...). I've decided to give it this type for unify all question's answers in the same table independently of the type of question. Is it a bad solution?